# One firefighter made off with a Los Angeles Fire Department cellphone

Tags: phrase-meaning

> #### At the LAFD, pay for sex on duty, batter a cop, lie on medical records — and keep your job
>
> **One firefighter made off with a Los Angeles Fire Department cellphone** last year and used it to solicit a prostitute while on
> duty. He then abandoned his dispatch post at the department’s downtown communications center, which handles 911 calls, drove to a hotel near Los Angeles International Airport and had sex with her before returning to work.

[Source: Los Angeles Times](https://www.latimes.com/california/story/2023-05-04/lafd-investigation-disciplinary-system)

Does "made off" here mean "ran away"? I've imagined two scenarios for it: (1) Police found the man doing something illegal red handed and he ran away from the police; (2) The man was on duty yet he went away from his post for the purpose of soliciting a prostitute.

Which? The (2) is more likely to me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Normally, "*make off with*" means to take something you shouldn't have and leave. It's usually applied to theft.

In this case, however, the journalist is inflating the situation with misleading language to make the situation seem even worse than it is. The firefighter likely left the fire department building to see a prostitute and had his work cell phone with him. The writer wanted to make this sound worse, so used the phrase "make off with" to suggest he also stole the phone, which makes little sense.

Comment: It says he worked as a dispatcher, which means he probably used a land-line and may not have had a work cell phone. Be even if, he would have wanted to call on a phone not traceable to him. I'm guessing he snagged an unused LAFD cell phone for those calls. If true, "made off with" seems like a short, accurate way of conveying that (the story is behind a paywall so I can't check, at least not in 5 minutes).

Comment: Generally *made off with* does mean *steal*, but I would argue in this case, the writer is using it to imply that it is a work issued phone being used a non-approved purpose. An employer may be able to make a legitimate argument that it was theft.

Comment: @PCLuddite I think it would be legitimate to use "made off with" to describe taking a car for a joy-ride, even though you return it. This seems akin to that.

Answer (score 6):

*Make off with*:

"(transitive) To steal (something) and flee"

- ([Wiktionary](https://(transitive)%20To%20steal%20(something)%20and%20flee.))

But in this case, I'm not sure that the writer is thinking about the "and flee" part - they  appear to simply mean "steal", and then they write about the "fleeing" separately.